# Why can I see spam/offensive chat flags?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, chat, privileges, flags

I have 8k on Gaming, and was sitting in The Bridge when I suddenly saw a blue chat notification. It was different from the usual yellow "Someone is replying to you" notification, so I clicked on it.

To my surprise, it was a spam/offensive flag for something on Ask Ubuntu.

I was under the impression that that was something that only happened at 10k, or if you were a moderator?

I have been over 8k for a while, but this is the first time I have seen a flag like this. I checked under the list of privileges, and there is no mention of being able to see these flags before 10k (unless I am just missing something).

Is this a bug? Or have I been granted new abilities that I just never noticed?

Comment: If you're bothered by this, see [Let me opt out of viewing chat flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125192/let-me-opt-out-of-viewing-chat-flags)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Privileges on `chat.stackexchange.com` are based on the sum of your reputation across all Stack Exchange sites, not your reputation on a specific site. [In your chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/15026/ashley-nunn) you can see that this adds up to 10489  reputation<sup>1</sup>, allowing you to see chat flags.

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is *slightly* less than the sum of the reputation scores visible in your profile because chat doesn't sync in real-time.</sub>