# Is there/Will there be more active development on the chat pages?

Tags: support, chat

I am an active user of the SO chat and there are a few things that bug me for example that ([until recently fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374690/6707985)) users could request access to a gallery room with 1 reputation or that the [chat page](https://chat.stackexchange.com) still looks.... Well how it looks:

[image]

Before I open feature-request question after question here mentioning the things I would love to see changed, I wondered if there is any active development on the chat going on. Active in the sense of the changes that for example the SE main pages get in voting systems (there is something going on on SO with a potential new delete/undelete system) or the big css changes that were rolled out to make the site responsive.
With the example above it is clear that there are changes made but that took almost 11 months until the issue was said to be solved.

Comment: Even with a yes or no answer, it will still take 6 to 8 weeks, give or take, to get something implemented.

Comment: I am aware that SE has limited dev resources (which company doesn't?). This question was mainly thought as guard before writing a bunch of feature-request questions that are then deemed as "low priority" and essentially age away.

Comment: I assume all feature requests I propose here will be deemed as "low priority" and essentially age away. It's just what they do.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing in my two cents: while the focus of SE is not towards chat these days, the term "Never say never" applies here. I am pretty sure that after completing several key projects, they will move the attention and focus towards other things, including chat.

Same way the profile page goes under complete makeover from time  to time, I'm pretty sure chat will get one too, at some point.

Surely not few weeks or few months, probably not even 1-2 years, but with enough patience we might see this in "our" days. :)

Bottom line: don't hold back from reporting bugs related to chat or suggesting new feature requests. Worst case you'll just get some reputation (usually) and they will wait patiently here.

Comment: While I really hope for the best in that regard it would be really great to get an official statement on this :D
And with the team being so eager to get the responsiveness rolled out everywhere, I was rather surprised to see the old and "dusty" topbar still in place in chat. But I guess there is more going on than just a little css here or there.