# Is this type of content 'inappropriate content' for the chat?

Tags: discussion, chat, flags, account-suspension

When today I connected to the chat (SOes) I saw that yesterday I was suspended 30 minutes for 'inappropriate content'.

I clicked on the notification and I saw the flagged message, it was this:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/51109359/history
https://isabellasradblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/adios-momma-jaeger.gif

I understand that someone can get annoyed by that gif even if I don't consider it inappropriate.

Is this type of content inappropriate or not? Movie/Anime scenes, songs that containt violence should not be tolerated?

Edit, age rating of the anime: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2560140/parentalguide

Comment: Only moderators can see the message you linked to. If you want opinions from non-mods please post a screenshot of the message. (Or the actual gif, but not as direct image please)

Comment: See: [We're more aggressively enforcing self-moderation in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309645/were-more-aggressively-enforcing-self-moderation-in-chat)

Comment: I've been trying to keep track of the scores, and it is probably worth noting that all of the answers seem to have been voted against all at once, at least twice so far. Unfortunately, they have not taken the time to write why, so we can't be sure, but what all of the answers share in common is that they endorse some amount of censorship here, even if the method of judgement differs, so I assume that those votes are against any sort of censorship. I think somebody who endorses that stance should write an actual answer to that effect, since otherwise the opinion is not given due representation.

Answer (score 12):

First, it should be noted that the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) notably does not have specific guidelines regarding gratuitously violent content, and it is largely couched in terms of interpersonal relationships. The generally prohibited categories are   "No name-calling or personal attacks", "No bigotry", and "No Harassment". Additionally, [the acceptable use policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) prohibits "Sexually Explicit Content" but states nothing about violence in particular.

I am not going to advocate that anything goes in regards to violence, but at the same time we really need to strike an acceptable balance here. We want the chatrooms to be as hospitable of a place as they can possibly be for everybody. If we are not censorious enough we risk driving away some members, and if we are too censorious we risk driving away other participants and render websites inoperable, because they are no longer a place where people can function to seriously discuss serious subject matter due to fear of hypersensitivity.

As a general rule of thumb, I think the best way to achieve this balance is probably to be aiming for website content that is on the *highest level of violence or eroticism* that would generally be considered acceptable for *even our youngest prospective members* members to view.

In order to comply with [The Children's Online Privacy Protection Act of 1998](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions), the Stack Exchange network's Public Terms of Service has an [age eligibility](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#age) section which requires that all members be *at least* 13 years old, which is convenient enough for us because this represents the lower limit of M.P.A.A. and E.S.R.B. age rating categories such as P.G. 13, or T for Teen. Somebody being eaten alive actually is not so big of a problem if we go by that rule.

Testing the image by that level of acceptability this image is a borderline case. In some respects it is better. The age ratings for the show this particular image is from, [Attack On Titan](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2560140/parentalguide), range from the lower teens to the upper teens depending on the region. We also do not actually see the person being bitten at all. You could argue that this is strawberry jam or ketchup.

[Jurassic Park is rated P.G. 13.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B1EEKM8) We do see dinosaurs eating people in that film, and [even see their bodies in their mouths being shaken around](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5Co3A3fLBo).

However, what we do not see in Jurassic Park is people bitten all of the way through, and shedding unrealistic levels of bloodshed. The amount of bloodshed in this image is probably its biggest problem, and probably pushes it past the general acceptability threshold. This amount of blood is disproportionate to the injury being inflicted, even in consideration of the injury's fatal nature: This makes it a highly gratuitous example, and it is more comparable to, or even in excess of, what we see in the Mortal Kombat games.

Mortal Kombat is a useful comparison because it stirred quite the controversy for the amount of violence it depicted upon first release), and one of the things Nintendo did in order to render it acceptable for the platform was change the red blood splatters into grey "sweat", which caused some color pallet problems. Eventually, [the E.S.R.B. was founded as a result of the controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_congressional_hearings_on_video_games), and while future Mortal Kombat games would be released uncensored, they have traditionally received the M for Mature rating, meant to mark games as only being acceptable for ages 17 and up, rather than the T for Teen rating. [*Mortal Kombat 3*](https://replayers.org/sega_genesis_roms/ultimate-mortal-kombat-3-usa-eur-sega-genesis-rom/) for the S.N.E.S. and Sega Genesis is rated M for instance. In that game it usually looks like there is [a pint of blood gushing out of the character](https://www.mobygames.com/game/arcade/ultimate-mortal-kombat-3/screenshots/gameShotId,657334/) with every high punch/kick shown in those games. Meanwhile, other fighting games like *Street Fighter II* which show [realistically bloodied faces on the game continuation screen](https://game-over-dex.fandom.com/wiki/Street_Fighter_II:_The_World_Warrior) squeak by with [a T for teen rating](https://www.esrb.org/ratings/search.aspx?searchType=title&platformsCriteria=Wii&titleOrPublisher=Super+Street+Fighter+II:+The+New+Challengers).

Granted, Mortal Kombat's problems extend far beyond the amount of blood shown in combat, so it is hard for me to say if the game would have been rated T if it were not for the fatalities but insofar as uncertainty goes, it is better to err on the side of caution. Under the bigotry provision of the code of conduct it says "When in doubt, just don't", and while strictly speaking violence is not the same as bigotry, it speaks to the proclivities of the Stack Exchange community, which I feel are overall more sensitive than most other websites, and is generally good advice anyway.

In consideration of these facts, I would suggest that as **a general rule of thumb**, I would suggest that *dripping* blood should be okay, but *gushing* blood is not.

However, it should also be noted that there should be exceptions where we should be able to the stretch the boundaries somewhat, if there is *good reason* to believe that the type of content shown would be considered *generally acceptable* by *prospective visitors* of a room. Personally speaking, I think that sort of image would be acceptable if shown at Anime Stack Exchange, out of consideration of a couple of factors.

The first is the fact that Attack on Titan is one of the more popular shows which is relevant to our particular field of interest, meaning that most of the people who might come to visit have already seen it, and that sort of content would be considered more acceptable amongst anime enthusiasts in general. I would suggest that we risk alienating more users there than we stand to gain with the more censorious approach. [We should have some leeway for room culture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270590/371286)
 when there is not a blatant code of conduct or terms of service violation.

More importantly, Stack Exchange is meant to be an academic website first and foremost, and there are some allowances to be made for relevant subject-matter. At English Language & Usage Jeff Atwood noted that [we may do as we see fit in the body of a post with respect to offensive language](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/975/do-we-really-need-to-add-nsfw-in-question-titles/981#981), but that offensive words should be censored in titles so that the general network is not exposed to it. There were further guidelines, although I think those were in now deleted comments. The point of that was not so much to abrogate the Code of Conduct/Be Nice policies, so much as to allow us to analyze words on an as needed basis.

What is and is not acceptable on a more local basis with respect to a given domain's subject matter should probably be left to the more local meta-websites to determine, unless the network as a whole is somehow involved.

Comment: @AsieR_2 IMHO in these types of questions should not have an accepted answer since it seems that you choose this answer because it seems that it is he who is very close to your initial position. In these types of questions, the community is expected to think with the answers and with the votes, and the most voted answer is the one that shows the community's consensus. Anyway this is my point of view so you can discard it, bye

Comment: @AsieR_2 I do not say that you can not mark it as correct, you can if you want, in this type of questions where there are many gray areas it is advisable not to mark as correct any question, since it has no weight since it is only your validation and not of the community, in these cases it is better to let the votes be the protagonists. Everyone is my opinion, if you want, do not take it into account.

Comment: @eyllanesc The green tick mark mean "accepted" not "correct"

Comment: @Rubén You are correct, I was sleepy, I should have said: *I do not say that you can not mark it as accepted, you can if you want...*

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this can be considered inappropriate on most Stack Exchange chat rooms.

Anything showing blood (or other bodily fluids) can be inappropriate, even if not showing actual people.

Comment: This could be inappropriate too? http://i.stack.imgur.com/7u1Vq.png

Comment: @AsieR_2 that one you linked here appears legit. Dunno about rating, but yes, keep in mind SE is being used by 13 years old teenagers. They don't need or want to see some things. It's not something black and white with clear boundaries, there's also a pretty big "gray zone". But the gif you posted in chat is not in any gray zone.

Comment: @AsieR_2 still, even if the TV show itself is OK, there usually are some scenes which are less appropriate. Even mainstream movies/TV shows with no age limit at all got nude scenes sometimes. See my point?

Comment: "Anything showing blood (or other bodily fluids) can be inappropriate" *posts a nervous sweating gif*

Comment: @ShaWiz There is any list about the content that sould not be tolerated? Or this is what you think should be? If there's not I dont see the problem of this kind of content on a site where you have to be +13. That applies to nudity if the context supports it.

Comment: @AsieR_2 It is not only a matter of age. I wouln't want that gif to show up at work when using Chat.

Comment: @ModusTollens Yeah, but that could apply to any anime related gif.

Comment: @AsieR_2 True. I don't know if you ask about any kind of chat, but I'd expect my programming related chats to keep it at least semi-professional, so no splatter effects or nudity, please.

Comment: @AsieR_2 no list and there can't be a list. Like I said, there is wide gray zone. Sometimes, even the same pic/gif posted in different times will bring different results. It's matter of common sense, and who see that content. My rule of thumb: if you're not sure, don't post it. And even that isn't bullet proof, got a gif flagged here on meta chat, it was a dog pee in a pot (potty training), turns out it's animal abuse but didn't realize it before posting, it was just a funny gif I've found.

Comment: @ShaWiz That shouldn't happen. There should be clear and concise rules. At least that is my opinion and that was what I was looking for in the answers.

Comment: @AsieR_2 sorry, but that's the result of SE being so diverse and making its best to please everyone. If there will be clear and strict rules, people won't use the chat. There must be some room for fun, and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @AsieR_2 "it's rated 12 in my country" see [the certifications](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2560140/parentalguide/certificates); it's R-18/M in other countries. (Just because your country rated it lower doesn't mean it's safe, but we all know TV rating is a broken system ;)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Most of them are 14-16, and the chat we are talking about is from my country...

Comment: @ShaWiz With an arbitrary system can't be room for fun.

Comment: @AsieR_2 the chat is not exclusive for a country. The [es.SO] site embraces people from many countries and cultures and not only Spain, and that needs to be taken into consideration (including the chat).

Comment: @AsieR_2 while the chat room is related to your country, but the room itself is hosted on Stack Exchange which is an international site, and all SE chat rooms in general are public for everyone and bound to SE's policy. On the other hand, no one prevents you from using any other chat systems (e.g. Discord seems popular, or maybe IRC) if you want to have a more loose/free chat (really, some SE users have done it)...

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. And where on that policy says this kind of content is not allowed? That's what im looking for.

Comment: @AsieR_2 basically on [We're more aggressively enforcing self-moderation in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309645) which links to [Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587). In short: let's not scare/disgust any potential new chat users who stumble upon your main site's chat room, and leaving because they think the whole chat room supports such violence (even if it's a joke... or not)...

Comment: @AsieR_2 yeah, what Andrew said. Don't be vulgar too, even if you're "among friends".

Comment: *traumatic flashbacks to all the verbal comments about bodily fluids in Shadow's Den and the Kenny bot commands.

Answer (score 7):

To some extent - well, depends on context and practically how folks react depends a lot on the room culture.

You had a few things that probably didn't work for you. Firstly - without context (and for anyone not spanish speaking, we have totally no context), that is a *tiny* bit disturbing. It might have gone unremarked in say, a chatroom on anime (I recognised that is probably from attack on titan?) and we'd have more folks who would get the context in english.

And honestly? *any* 10ker or mod could have chosen to validate the flag. Someone clearly felt it was at the very least out of place.

It can be said to be arbitrary, but in a shared social space - it pays to be mindful of the folks around you *precisely* to avoid this sort of situations.

*Especially* amoungst friends, well, we can be a little insensitive, and a bit oblivious  sometimes, and folks can be too polite to say something's disturbing directly

So, more than one person found it disturbing enough.

And *unfortunately* if we can't moderate chat ourselves - by folks actually stepping up and trying to let folks know something dosen't belong, sometimes folks are going to step in.

Practically, if you're going to literally go "this is rated for these ages" and work hard to justify something being acceptable... we're already on the road to nopesville

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is an inappropriate content for the chat.

[The Stack Exchange Network and his communities are based in respect to others](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44746/moderadores-soes), please don´t make post that can be annoying for others considering you will be in a room with people from different cultures. Being a user in [Stackoverflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) chat you must know that one word or image in the place where you live could have a different context and a gross meaning in other place of the world.

[image]

I have seen some images posted that intrinsicaly have meanings that are not allowed in some sites.

I suggest, please consider moderate the content of your posts and you will not have any problems in the chat, make friends and have fun but respecting others.

https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy

Comment: I can't understand the point of your reply. I have readed all the links you have here before making my question. Also, this question is not about language.

Comment: Is related with the code of conduct that you must follow for the Stack Exchange Network, Please don´t try to justify something that´s not acceptable with the "rating for these ages", remember you are in an international site.

Comment: As I told you, I have read it. And there's nothing related to this there. That's why I'm asking here. And because I talked with a mod first and he told me to ask here.

Comment: Well, in that case, if you consider this answer as not related, check the other answers. Probably you will find the same answer the mod gave you previously...

Comment: I have the answer, not the reason behind, but it will have to be enough. In any case, thanks for participating and responding.