# What sorts of links to outside sites are appropriate on chat in particular?

Tags: discussion, chat, hyperlinks, chat-stars

I've been told there may be some sort of policy against linking to outside chats from SE chats. Is this true? In general, are there guidelines on which sort of links to outside sites are appropriate in chat? Does it make a difference if the comment is starred or pinned? Does it vary depending on which SE site the chat is associated with, or on whether the chat is public or private?

(For that matter, I'm also struggling to find central official guidance on links to outside sites from main SE sites, beyond discussion about issues with "link-only answers", but in this question I am particularly interested in the situation for chat.)

P.S. I could probably use some help with tagging. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that just a room directive? Not a general applicable rule. SOCVR has for example the [no one-box rule](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-not-noisy).

Comment: I assume the sites you link to do not fall in the NSFW category?

Comment: @rene I agree that any NSFW link from chat or the main site would be entirely inappropriate (though perhaps there are some extreme edge cases I am missing). Maybe I should explain that I am a (new) moderator at MO. There is a chat associated with my site where the room host is interested in pinning a link to an outside chat which has substantial overlap in terms of people chatting. In this particular case I can personally vouch for the outside chat, but I can see that allowing such things in general might be problematic. Perhaps I should discuss the details of this case with other moderators.

Comment: I don't think SE or anyone else really cares what gets pinned/linked by the Room Owners. As long as it is within the CoC, chat guidance and per-site guidance anything goes in a room. The only concern I would have: make clear you don't moderate outside of the SE venue and you don't allow spill overs from outside to cause a stir inside an SE venue. That is about it. If the RO team didn't yet have a FAQ or a rulebook to follow I wouldn't moderate too much in it. People will find external venues anyway, linked /pinned or not.

Comment: You have seen: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309645 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat ?

Comment: @rene Thanks, I had seen some of that stuff before, but had not read thoroughly. In particular, one premise of my question -- the idea that there _exists_ a lot of fixed SE-wide policy on detailed questions like this -- seems to be flawed.

Comment: Chat is a whole league on its own, has different dynamics, lacks proper mod-tools (or so I'm told), has a smaller userbase and when things go out of hand they escalate at high speed.

Comment: @rene Not sure if this question was asked in regards to this, but the Science Fiction & Fantasy room has a policy against linking to a specific off-site chat, which was (formerly) operated by a couple of users who had been permabanned from SE chat due to repeated CoC violations.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog yeah, I can see how per room policies are in place. AFAIK there is no SE wide single policy on this. Use common sense is probably the best you can get.