# 10K users should not see chat flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, chat, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

As it currently stands, all users with more than 10K reputation can see flags on chat. This, however, might not be constructive.

Whenever a swarm of flags (or, really, any single flag) comes up, all 10K users on the chat network are alerted. This doesn't make much sense; the only thing this can cause is more drama, as many chatrooms over a certain number of users tend to flare up with "what's going on over here?" comments.

Removing the 10K ability to process flags actually wouldn't worsen the condition of chat, either - and it actually might improve it:

- Discussion about drama would be kept to the Teachers' Lounge, where it will be safe and sound and cause the least disturbance to people across the network.
- Many 10K users I've talked with actually *don't* want to see these things, since they don't have enough contextual information to handle problems, and can't do anything about these flags.
- Room discussions won't be derailed by large quantities of flags in other rooms.

It's not for want of manpower that flags aren't useful: it's actually a case where *too many* people have control over the outcome of a situation, so the case can't be given enough time to be reviewed properly. The ability for 10K users to handle flags certainly was more useful - and more necessary - when the network was smaller; however, now that the network has grown, there are pretty much always moderators on-hand who are available for flag-handling.

Comment: It's not about drama. This let ordinary users deal quickly with offensive messages, when there are no moderators around. I support [making it possible to opt out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125192/let-me-opt-out-of-viewing-chat-flags?rq=1), but not this suggestion to just cut out the privilege.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Speaking from experience, there are always moderators around. The Stack Exchange network is very, _very_ large now. I can say something in TL at pretty much any time of the day, any time of the year, and someone will be there to respond.

Comment: The 10k threshold was also set back when there were fewer users overall and you had to work a little to reach 10k across the network.  If it's still desirable for non-mods to handle flags, maybe it's time to raise the threshold.

Comment: Or revoke it from 10K users but give it to room owners.

Comment: @Emrakul This is only true for Chat.SE, not for Chat.SO

Comment: @MadScientist Fair point. If the two were merged, that would be a non-issue, but if they remain separate, it might be worth considering Stack Overflow on its own.

Comment: I find that sometimes the 10k are also the ones getting ["surprised about the flags"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat) in the first place, so I for one totally agree at leaving the chat flags in the Stack Exchange staff hands.