# "Counterflagging" Catch-22

Tags: support, chat, chat-flags

I just got a notification in chat regarding a message tagged as offensive somewhere.  I have not noticed this before, I don't know if it is new.

It was not offensive, so I clicked "no".  I then got a popup saying "Your vote as a moderator is binding...", I clicked continue.

I then got a banner saying,

> ### You can only counterflag messages that have been flagged

I tried this another couple of times to watch the loop again.  I don't know if this is because the flag had been cleared and/or is the result of a defect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens when the flag was already dealt with before you tried to clear it. Flags in chat get cleared very, very quickly due to the large number of moderators and 10k users on chat at any time.

[There are proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270270/215468) to simply remove 10ker access to these flags on chat.SE, as there are simply so many moderators now that we don't really need anyone else seeing chat flags.

Comment: considering that sometime the 10k users seem to be the same users that as Shog9 said are often oddly ticked off by the fact that someone *dared* flagging in the first place, the removal sound a good idea.