# How should we deal with flags for chat messages for rooms that are in a different language?

Tags: discussion, chat, languages, chat-flags

I've posted an answer touching on this before at [Let me opt out of viewing chat flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125192/let-me-opt-out-of-viewing-chat-flags/313532#313532):

> Here's the problem: I am mostly in The Bridge, the gaming chat. I see
>   chat flags from the Russian, Chinese, Spanish, French, Ukrainian,
>   Latin, Korean, Italian, Esperanto, Japanese and Portuguese stacks. I
>   don't speak any of these languages and don't want to learn them
>   either, yet I am still asked to review chat flags from these stacks.
>
> I don't know what they are saying. It could be a dumb joke, it could
>   be insults thrown at each other, or they could be conspiring to end
>   democracy. I just don't know. I am just not qualified to review these
>   messages, and I'm fairly sure that the vast majority of the other chat
>   users are in the same situation, simply because they don't know what
>   is being said.
>
> I don't want to press valid or invalid, because of the chance of false
>   positives. and if enough people press "Not Sure", the flag gets
>   invalidated as well, so I don't really see how that's an option
>   either.

Note that some of these languages only rarely throw me chat flags, and some of them I only speculate they might be thrown. I don't think I've seen an Esperanto or Latin flag yet, but I regularly see Russian flags.

Since that didn't get any real interactions, I wanted to specifically ask this question manually: How should I deal with chat flags for languages I don't speak?