# I can see chat flags without 10k

Tags: bug, chat, chat-flags

On Stack Overflow, I don't have 10k, but I *can* see chat flags (on chat.SO). Not when I'm just in the room, but when I go to a message's history, I can see a blue square next to it if it's flagged. (and I was not the flagger)

[image: Chat flags]

Comment: Good to know, but no `"event_type": 9` comes through the websockets when you're not the flagger, which may be part of why it didn't update visually within the chat window itself.

Comment: This just happened to me today. I found your question out of nine tagged [tag:chat-flags]. Thanks for posting! :)

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87761/255554) the 10 k privileges for chat only depend on your global reputation, even for StackOverflow (while everything else is separate for Stack Overflow). So, what you experienced may be intended behaviour. However, this may be outdated.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121263/255554) is another post confirming that the 10 k chat privileges are coming from network reputation, which is marked [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). However, this does not address any special cases for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is not true: a user on chat.SO's privileges are based on their rep on SO, a user on chat.mSE's privileges are based on their rep on mSE, and a user on chat.SE's privileges are based on their combined network reputation.

Comment: I think this is not what I'm experiencing. If that would be the case, I would get a blue circle that indicates there is a flag. I have 10k global reputation so I know how it looks like on chat.SE, but I've never seen it on chat.SO (not even for this flag), so I don't think this is the reason.